# How to access a Model that isn't part of a Controller in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am currently working in a controller called Content. In this controller, I have a function that will be called when someone goes on to the homepage, and most of the data will be pulled from the Content model.

However, I want to display data from another model called Phones. When I type this code:

```
$phones = $this->Phone->find('all');
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

When I change the `Phone` part of the PHP code to `Content` it works fine. So I'm guessing that I can't, at the moment, access the Phone model from inside the Content controller.

Is there a way to achieve a way of accessing a model externally from a controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->loadModel('Phone'); # Important: singular!!!
$this->set('phones', $this->Phone->find('all'));
```

Comment: also note: you can always use $Model = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName') as well (in other classes than controllers)

Answer (score 1):

try with below

```
$this->loadModel('Phone');
$this->set('phones', $this->Phone->find('all'));
```

cheers